# Xcode add dependencies to my custom package

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, swift-package-manager

I have a problem when adding the firebase package to my custom module (package) that manages the authentication.

In the `Package.swift` file I had the following code:

```
dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk", .upToNextMajor(from: "9.0.0")),
],
```

The problem is that this code is going to add all the services that the `firebase-ios-sdk` provides. There is a way to add the "sub-service" that this package provides? Like FirebaseAuth, FirebaseAnalytics.

Comment: I found the solution here: [how to add a single module](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md#alternatively-add-firebase-to-a-packageswift-manifest)

Answer (score 1):

I get your problem and I've been in the same situation. Take the following `package.swift`, where Firebase is added as a dependency.

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageName",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "PackageName",
            targets: ["PackageName"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "9.0.0")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "PackageName",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseCrashlytics", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
            ])
    ]
)
```